# Override page numbers of a djvu document

Tags: djvu, numbering, documents

I have a djvu scan of a book. Let's consider two cases:

1. I'd like to number the pages `0, 1, 2, ...` (usage case: the cover should get be page 0)
2. I'd like to number some pages with Roman numbers and some with Arabic numbers, for example: `i, ii, iii, ..., x, 1, 2, 3, ...` (usage  case: some introductory pages are numbered Roman in the book)

Is it possible to do it on Linux?

Comment: Whatever the platform, this will require a specific tool that works with lowlevel djvu specification. Just hope there is a `djvulibre` expert here.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but if you have to ask it's unlikely to be very useful to you.  You'll need a script that produces a sequence of `set-page-title` commands like this:

```
select 1; set-page-title "Cover"
select 2; set-page-title "i"
select 3; set-page-title "ii"
select 4; set-page-title "iii"
select 5; set-page-title "1"
select 6; set-page-title "2"
select 7; set-page-title "3"
select 8; set-page-title "4"
select 9; set-page-title "5"
select 10; set-page-title "6"
...
```

You have to pipe the output of the script to `djvused` to commit the changes to your DjVu file:

```bash
djvu_pagination | djvused -f - -s file.djvu
```

Beware however that you have only once chance at this, if you get the numbers wrong you won't be able to run the same command again, you'll have to reset logical page numbers by referencing the component names.  That goes something like this:

```
select "all_24223_to_00243.cpc.djvu"; set-page-title "all_24223_to_00243.cpc.djvu"
select "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0002.djvu"; set-page-title "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0002.djvu"
select "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0003.djvu"; set-page-title "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0003.djvu"
select "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0004.djvu"; set-page-title "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0004.djvu"
select "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0005.djvu"; set-page-title "all_24223_to_00243.cpc0005.djvu"
...
```

You'd then pipe these commands to `djvused` as above:

```
djvu_reset_pagination | djvused -f - -s file.djvu
```

Once upon a time people used to have scripts to handle all that.  Those days are now long gone.

Comment: I have had no problems reusing the same type of commands again, but the instructions for resetting logical page numbers don't hurt anyway.

Comment: Note: ``echo "select "$iTOTAL"; set-page-title \""$iROMAN"\""`` is bad syntax. You are quoting the literal strings (which don’t *need* to be quoted) and leaving the shell variables (which should always be quoted) unquoted.

Comment: @lcd047 "Once upon a time people used to have scripts to handle all that. Those days are now long gone." I am intrigued by this statement; who were these DJVU adepts? Why are those days long gone? Is there a history recorded somewhere?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver _who were these DJVU adepts?_ - Mostly [pirates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library.nu) (allegedly). _Why are those days long gone?_ - Because people chose PDF instead, which had professionally-written editing tools, and the backing of the industry, while DjVu had been abandoned by its creators.

Answer (score 1):

**Update March 2021: Updated script + skipping pages**

(adapted from lcd047's answer)

Create a backup copy of your .djvu file in case something goes wrong.

Install the `numconv` package from [here](https://billposer.org/Software/libuninum.html#downloads).

Save the following as a text file e.g. `generate_page_list.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Set these parameters:
# Name first/last page $CNAME/$BCNAME? (Yes/No=0/1)
COVER=1
BCOVER=0
CNAME="C"
BCNAME="BC"
# Lowest roman page number 
MINROMAN=3
# Highest roman page number
MAXROMAN=6
# Lowest arabic page number
MINARABIC=1
# Highest arabic page number
MAXARABIC=10

# Create/Empty new_page_list
> new_page_list
# Initialise total page number iTOTAL
iTOTAL=1
# Generate list of set-page-title commands
if [[ "$COVER" == 1 ]]; then
    echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$CNAME\"" >> new_page_list
    ((iTOTAL++))
fi

for (( i=$MINROMAN; i<=$MAXROMAN; i++)); do
    iROMAN=`echo $i | numconv -f Western -t Roman_Lower`
    echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$iROMAN\"" >> new_page_list
    ((iTOTAL++))
done

for (( i=$MINARABIC; i<=$MAXARABIC; i++)); do
    echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$i\"" >> new_page_list
    ((iTOTAL++))
done

if [[ "$BCOVER" == 1 ]]; then
    echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$BCNAME\"" >> new_page_list
    ((iTOTAL++))
fi
```

Make `generate_page_list.sh` executable via

```
chmod +x generate_page_list.sh
```

Run the script via

```
./generate_page_list.sh
```

This produces a file `new_page_list`. Open this file in a text editor to check it contains a sequence of `set-page-title` commands like this:

```
select 1; set-page-title "Cover"
select 2; set-page-title "i"
select 3; set-page-title "ii"
select 4; set-page-title "iii"
select 5; set-page-title "1"
select 6; set-page-title "2"
select 7; set-page-title "3"
select 8; set-page-title "4"
select 9; set-page-title "5"
select 10; set-page-title "6"
...
```

Pass this list to `djvused` to commit the changes to your DjVu file:

```bash
djvused -f new_page_list -s file.djvu
```

## Script with skipped pages

If your .djvu files has missing pages (e.g. empty pages left out when skanning), you can use the following extension of the above skript:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## Set these parameters:
# Name first/last page $CNAME/$BCNAME? (Yes/No=0/1)
COVER=1
BCOVER=0
CNAME="C"
BCNAME="BC"
# Lowest roman page number 
MINROMAN=3
# Highest roman page number
MAXROMAN=6
# Skipped roman page numbers 
SKIPROMAN=""
# Lowest arabic page number
MINARABIC=1
# Highest arabic page number
MAXARABIC=10
# Skipped arabic page numbers
SKIPARABIC="3 5"

# Create/Empty new_page_list
> new_page_list
# Initialise total page number iTOTAL
iTOTAL=1
# Generate list of set-page-title commands
if [[ "$COVER" == 1 ]]; then
    echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$CNAME\"" >> new_page_list
    ((iTOTAL++))
fi

for (( i=$MINROMAN; i<=$MAXROMAN; i++)); do
    if [[ ! " $SKIPROMAN " =~ " $i " ]]; then
        iROMAN=`echo $i | numconv -f Western -t Roman_Lower`
        echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$iROMAN\"" >> new_page_list
        ((iTOTAL++))
    fi
done

for (( i=$MINARABIC; i<=$MAXARABIC; i++)); do
    if [[ ! " $SKIPARABIC " =~ " $i " ]]; then
        echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$i\"" >> new_page_list
        ((iTOTAL++))
    fi
done

if [[ "$BCOVER" == 1 ]]; then
    echo "select $iTOTAL; set-page-title \"$BCNAME\"" >> new_page_list
    ((iTOTAL++))
fi
```

SKIPARABIC (resp. SKIPROMAN) is a string containing a list of page numbers to be skipped, separated by spaces. You can, for example, enter numbers individually:

```bash
SKIPARABIC="3 4"
```

or as a range

```bash
SKIPARABIC="{3..5}"
```

or a combination of one or more numbers and ranges (again separated by spaces

```bash
SKIPARABIC="{3..5} 7 {9..15}"
```

I am using string comparison (according to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394738/8672460)), which may not be the most efficient, but it was the easiest and most readable solution I could find for skipping iterations in a loop according to a list.

Answer (score 0):

**Update November 2023: hife's answer without dependency on `numconv`**

The [answer by hife](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578110/434806) on this page relies on the package `numconv` to convert arabic numbers to roman numerals. However, I had trouble installng `numconv` on my kubuntu system. Namely, it seemed to install normally, but when invoked, it returned the error `numconv: error while loading shared libraries: libuninum.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` (even though the library was where it presumably was supposed to be, in `/usr/local/lib/`).

I have therefore written a bash script that performs the conversion, `arabic_to_roman`. It is basically a transliteration into bash of the algorithm presented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211123120155/https://helloacm.com/how-to-convert-arabic-integers-to-roman-numerals/). The script is given at the end of this post.

The only change required in hife's scripts is in this command:

```
iROMAN=`echo $i | numconv -f Western -t Roman_Lower`
```

That command should be replaced by

```
iROMAN=`arabic_to_roman $i`
```

In order for this to work, the script `arabic_to_roman` should be in a directory that's in the search path; othewise, you need to provide the full path to the script. And of course, the script should be made executable (e.g. by using `chmod +x arabic_to_roman`).

Finally, here is the script `arabic_to_roman`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# sample usage: 
# arabic_to_roman 54
# returns liv

# Function to convert Arabic number to Roman numeral
convert_to_roman() {
    num=$1
    res=""

    while [ $num -ge 1000 ]; do
        res+="m"
        ((num-=1000))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 900 ]; do
        res+="cm"
        ((num-=900))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 500 ]; do
        res+="d"
        ((num-=500))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 400 ]; do
        res+="cd"
        ((num-=400))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 100 ]; do
        res+="c"
        ((num-=100))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 90 ]; do
        res+="xc"
        ((num-=90))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 50 ]; do
        res+="l"
        ((num-=50))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 40 ]; do
        res+="xl"
        ((num-=40))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 10 ]; do
        res+="x"
        ((num-=10))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 9 ]; do
        res+="ix"
        ((num-=9))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 5 ]; do
        res+="v"
        ((num-=5))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 4 ]; do
        res+="iv"
        ((num-=4))
    done

    while [ $num -ge 1 ]; do
        res+="i"
        ((num-=1))
    done

    echo "$res"
}

# Check if an argument is provided
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <arabic_number>"
    exit 1
fi

# Call the function with the provided Arabic number
convert_to_roman $1
```